# OpenLayers2 addUniqueValueRules default style not displaying

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I'm trying to alter the colour of displayed points using `addUniqueValueRules` in OpenLayers. If I don't use `addUniqueValueRules` all my points display the default colour (green). However, when I add `addUniqueValueRules`, only those points that meet the rules are drawn.

The relevant code:

```
var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    fillOpacity: 1,
    fillColor: "green",
    pointRadius: 5
});

var styleLookup = {
    "Hög": { fillColor: "red" },
    "Måttlig": { fillColor: "yellow" },
    "Undersöka": { fillColor: "cyan" }
};

styleMap.addUniqueValueRules( "default", "risk", styleLookup );

wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
    strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), saveStrategy],
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: "1.1.0",
        srsName: "EPSG:4326",
        url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/tinyows",
        featurePrefix: "tows",
        featureNS :  "http://www.tinyows.org/",
        featureType: "tradcopy",
        geometryName: "geom"
    }),
    styleMap: styleMap
});
```

Can anyone help me draw all the points - both default and the ones that meet the rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addUniqueValueRules` implies that features that do not match the `lookup` object won't be rendered. I don't know if this is by design but the responsible code is [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Style.js#L190). If your `Style` have rules (which is not the case when you don't use `addUniqueValueRules`) and none of them were matched, then the feature is hidden.

This is the workaround I came up with:

```
var lookup = {
    "OpenLayers.Feature.Vector_1329": {
        fillColor: '#FF0000'
    }
};

this.drawingLayer.styleMap.addUniqueValueRules('default','name',lookup);
this.drawingLayer.styleMap.styles.default.rules.push(new OpenLayers.Rule({
    elseFilter: true,
    symbolizer: this.drawingLayer.styleMap.styles.default.defaultStyle
}));
```

What it does is simply defining an else rule that takes the default style as a symbolizer.